# How can I build multiple inputs into my shiny app with both updating and multiple selection?

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, flexdashboard

I am building a `flex dashboard` / `shiny` app with a `datatable` and trying to build in two inputs as selections for this `datatable` with an "All" choice for each selection. First question is how can I limit the second selection `"user"` by the selection of the first choice `"team"`?

Then, using these inputs, I'd like to subset my data to any combination of the two selections ex. Team All, user "Darwin D" would return a single line datatable with his name, team and other metrics to be added etc.

All code for a flex markdown document below:

````
---
title: "example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)
library(magrittr)
library(feather)
library(anytime)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(datasets)


Name <- c("Allan A","Barbara B","Charles C","Darwin D","Evelyn E","Frank F","Greg G","Hans H")
Team <- c(1,2,3,3,2,1,2,2)
users <- data.frame(Name,Team)
remove(Name,Team)
```



Inputs {.sidebar}
=======================================================================

### Input Variables

```{r global_input}
# input variable to call selection, name of field, selections/options variable
dateRangeInput('dateRange',
     label = 'Date range input: yyyy-mm-dd',
     start = Sys.Date() - 8,
     end = Sys.Date() - 1,
     min = "2013-01-01",
     max = Sys.Date() -1
   )

selectInput("teaminput","Team", c("All",unique(users$Team)))

observe({
    if( input$teaminput == "All" ) {
        subDT <- copy( users )
    } else {
        subDT <- users[ users$Team == input$teaminput, ]
    }

    updateSelectInput(
        "userinput",
        label = "User Name",
        choices = c( "All", unique(subDT$Name ) )
    )
})
```

### Intake Coordinator KPIs

```{r daily_table}
# reactive data object based on inputs above
daily_dt <- reactive({
  if(input$teaminput == "All"){
      subDT
}  else{
    subset(subDT$Team == input$teaminput)
}
  })

# render DT datatable object with sorts/search
renderDataTable(daily_dt())
```
````

Comment: Added a full code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use 2 `reactive`, the first one to filter the data.frame by Team, the second to filter the result of the first one by Name :

````
---
title: "example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(DT)

users <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Allan A","Barbara B","Charles C","Darwin D","Evelyn E","Frank F","Greg G","Hans H"),
  Team = c(1,2,3,3,2,1,2,2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
=======================================================================
### Input Variables

```{r global_input}
selectInput("teaminput","Team",c("All", unique(users$Team)), selected="All")
selectInput("userinput","User Name", c("All", unique(users$Name) ), selected="All")

teamFiltered <- reactive(users[input$teaminput=="All" | users$Team==input$teaminput,])

observe(updateSelectInput(session,"userinput", choices = c("All", unique(teamFiltered()$Name)), selected="All"))
```

Results
=======================================================================
### Intake Coordinator KPIs

```{r daily_table}
userFiltered <- reactive(teamFiltered()[input$userinput=="All" | teamFiltered()$Name==input$userinput,])

renderDataTable(userFiltered())
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Note I can't test this unless you provide a reproducible example, but something along these lines should work. You need a reactive function in your `server`, which includes a subsetting step, and an `updateSelectInput` call. This will update the input in your `ui` any time the reactive is triggered.

```
observe({
    if( input$team == "All" ) {
        subDT <- copy( DT )
    } else {
        subDT <- DT[ Team == input$team, ]
    }

    updateSelectInput(
        "user",
        label = "User Name",
        choices = c( "All", unique( subDT$Name ) )
    )

})
```

So any time `input$team` is changed, we create a subset based on that selection, and use that subset to update the `user` input field.

Comment: Added. I see where you are going with this - perfect. What about on the output side? Do you think the nested subframe would be best? The implementation I had tried to go for was a conditional selection of 4 outcomes: Both = all, Team = selected, Name = selected, Team and Name = selected.  Does that make sense?