# Filtering data with selections and checkboxes in Flexdashboard

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, flexdashboard

In a flexdashboard, I want to allow a selection by having selectInput() combined with a checkboxGroupInput(). But the data is not updated correctly and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I used the toy example from this SO-example [[LINK]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148177/how-can-i-build-multiple-inputs-into-my-shiny-app-with-both-updating-and-multipl) and included a checkbox. It seems that the Checkbox is still ignored and messes up the other parts of the code.

It would be great if someone could adjust the code so that selection can be based on one of the three columns Team, Name or Year.

````
---
title: "example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(DT)
library(shiny)

users <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Allan A","Barbara B","Charles C","Darwin D","Evelyn E","Frank F","Greg G","Hans H"),
  Team = c(1,2,3,3,2,1,2,2),
  Year = c(1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2003,2003), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
=======================================================================
### Input Variables

```{r global_input}

### selection Input based on columns Team and Name
selectInput("teaminput","Team",c("All", unique(users$Team)), selected="All")
selectInput("userinput","User Name", c("All", unique(users$Name) ), selected="All")

### Add Input from CheckboxGroup based on Year starting with all
checkboxGroupInput("yearinput", label = "Year",choices =  unique(users$Year), selected=unique(users$Year), inline = TRUE)


### Filter Team based on one of the three choices (Team, Name, Year)
teamFiltered <- reactive(users[input$teaminput=="All" | 
                                 users$Team==input$teaminput |
                                 users$Year ==input$yearinput,])

### Observe if userinput changes based on SELECTION
observe(updateSelectInput(session,"userinput", 
                          choices = c( unique(teamFiltered()$Name)), 
                          selected="All"))

### Observe if yearinput changes based on CHECK BOX
observe(updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"yearinput", 
                                  choices =  teamFiltered()$Year,
                                  selected="All"))

```

Results
=======================================================================
### Intake Coordinator KPIs

```{r daily_table}
userFiltered <- reactive(teamFiltered()[input$userinput=="All" | 
                         teamFiltered()$Name==input$userinput | 
                         teamFiltered()$Year==input$yearinput,])

renderDataTable(userFiltered())
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

users <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Allan A","Barbara B","Charles C","Darwin D","Evelyn E","Frank F","Greg G","Hans H"),
  Team = c(1,2,3,3,2,1,2,2),
  Year = c(1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2003,2003),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(

### selection Input based on columns Team and Name
selectInput("teaminput","Team",c("All", unique(users$Team)), selected= "All", multiple = TRUE),
selectInput("userinput","User Name", c("All", unique(users$Name) ), selected="All", multiple = TRUE),

### Add Input from CheckboxGroup based on Year starting with all
checkboxGroupInput("yearinput", label = "Year",choices =  unique(users$Year), selected=unique(users$Year), inline = TRUE),
DTOutput("t1")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
### Filter Team based on one of the three choices (Team, Name, Year)
teamFiltered <- reactive(users["All" %in% input$teaminput |
                                 users$Team %in% input$teaminput,])

### Observe if userinput changes based on SELECTION
observeEvent(c(input$yearinput,input$teaminput), {
  updateSelectInput(session,"userinput", choices = c( unique(teamFiltered()$Name)), selected=unique(teamFiltered()$Name)
                    )
  })

### Observe if yearinput changes based on CHECK BOX
observeEvent(c(input$userinput,input$teaminput), {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"yearinput", choices =  unique(teamFiltered()$Year),
                                 selected=unique(teamFiltered()$Year))
  })

  ### Intake Coordinator KPIs

userFiltered <- reactive(teamFiltered()[ "All" %in% input$userinput |
                                          teamFiltered()$Name %in% input$userinput &
                                          teamFiltered()$Year %in% input$yearinput,])

output$t1 <- renderDT(userFiltered())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: When I use that code, I cannot filter via Team and Name. Only year is working.

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: Sorry, still the same problem. When I choose a team or a name, nothing happens.

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, it works! I did not figure out that I have to delete (!) a name so it is working. Many thanks!